# Java dosen't recognize that object belongs to subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, instanceof

So I'm doing some coursework about making a little game's prototype. I have these simple classes (and some others that are not relevant):

```
abstract class Weapon {
    int damage;
    int cost; 
}

abstract class RangedWeapon extends Weapon {
    int range;
    int rounds;
}

class ExtraRounds extends Item{
    int cost = 20;
    int uses = 1;
    void use(GameState state){
        if (state.currentCharacter.weapon instanceof RangedWeapon){
            state.currentCharacter.weapon.rounds += 10;
        }
    }

}
```

but when trying to compile this I'm getting

```
Implementations.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
            state.currentCharacter.weapon.rounds += 10;
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable rounds
  location: variable weapon of type Weapon
```

All I want is the class `ExtraRounds` to check if the `weapon` is of class `RangedWeapon` and act accordingly, but I don't know where things are going wrong. Any help is appreciated

Comment: the class Weapon has no "rounds" field, so you'll need to cast it to a RangedWeapon first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your weapon is of a Weapon class. You have to cast it to a RangedWeapon in order to your compiler know it is a RangedWeapon:

```
if (state.currentCharacter.weapon instanceof RangedWeapon){
   ((RangedWeapon)state.currentCharacter.weapon).rounds += 10;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you declare `state.currentCharacter.weapon` as `Weapon`, then you attemp to access its `rounds` field.

At compile stage, the compiler only know it is `Weapon`, and `Weapon` does not has`rounds`.

You can cast to `RangedWeapon` to make it compile:

```
if (state.currentCharacter.weapon instanceof RangedWeapon){
    RangedWeapon rangedWeapon = (RangedWeapon)state.currentCharacter.weapon;
    rangedWeapon.rounds += 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast **state.currentCharacter.weapon** to **RangedWeapon** after checking whether it has that type:

```
RangedWeapon rangedWeapon = (RangedWeapon) state.currentCharacter.weapon;
rangedWeapon.rounds +=10;
```

Comment: your solution won't compile, since you are trying to cast 'rounds' to a RangedWeapon (first mistake)

Answer (score 0):

`state.currentCharacter.weapon` is an instance of `RangedWeapon`, however its attribute `rounds` is `hidden` because `state.currentCharacter.weapon` is under `Weapon` type.

To turn on the attributes of `RangedWeapon` class, you have to explicitly cast it to `RangedWeapon` class:

```
RangedWeapon rangedWeapon = ((RangedWeapon) state.currentCharacter.weapon);
rangedWeapon.rounds +=10;
```